# Checking :hidden is not working inside element toggle

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

Inside `slideToggle()`, when element is visible, I want to do a specific task. When, element is hidden, I want to do another task. So, I have arranged the code like this:

```
if($('.element').is(':visible')) {
  // do something
} else {
  // do something   
}
```

But, it seems that `else` method is not working. How to make it works?

[Fiddle work](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/zt67pbkg/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `if` condition at all, you can just toggle both classes at the same time:

```
$('body').on('click', '.open', function() {  
    $('.openning').slideToggle();
    $(this).find('.glyphicon').toggleClass('glyphicon-chevron-down glyphicon-chevron-up');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zt67pbkg/1/)

Comment: Thanks. It works. But, I needed to know for applying large functionality(not just toggle another element), how can be it handled during visible and hidden. I got the answer from Arun. But, for small functionality like my sample fiddle, it's perfect toggling both the classes.

Comment: In that case you would need to place the logic within the callback parameter of the `slideToggle()`

Comment: Yes, that's exactly I needed to know. As Arun deleted his answer and your solution solve the problem of my Sample fiddle, I am ending this. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and with this if condition please see my code 
I check if condition like this

```
    if($('.openning').css('display') == "none") 




it is getting both events 
    $('body').on('click', '.open', function() {  
        $('.openning').slideToggle();
        alert($('.openning').css('display'));
        if($('.openning').css('display') == "none") {
            alert("out");
            $(this).find('.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');
        } else {
            alert("in");
            $(this).find('.glyphicon').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');  
        }
    });
```